# What are these dots in this boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, diagram

[Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cluen.png)

I created a boxplot for a data set and did not use the geom_jitter function. Still there are dots inside the plot. Are those statistical values or why are they appearing?

I attached the code I use below.

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, readxl, janitor, emmeans, multcomp, magrittr,
               parameters, effectsize, multcompView, see, performance,
               conflicted, ggpubr, rstatix)
conflict_prefer("select", "dplyr")
conflict_prefer("filter", "dplyr")
conflict_prefer("summarise", "dplyr")
conflict_prefer("extract", "magrittr")

cbPalette <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7") ## Color blind friendly palette
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Funktion um Excel Datei mit mehreren Sheets zu öffnen und eines davon auszuwählen
library(readxl)    
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename) {
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
  x <- lapply(sheets, function(x) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = x))
  return(x)
}

big_tbl <- read_excel_allsheets ("Mesocosms_R.xlsx")
big_tbl

phyto_plankton_tbl<- big_tbl[[14]]
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Data transformation
phyto_plankton_tbl %>% 
  mutate(
  block = as.factor(block),
  trt = factor(trt, labels = c("-P&-F", "+P/-F", "+P/+F", "-P/+F")))

phyto_plankton_tbl <- phyto_plankton_tbl %>% 
  gather(key = "time", value = "PelaChl", t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5) %>%  ## Ändert Tabelle aus width format into long format
  convert_as_factor(trt, time)
print(phyto_plankton_tbl, n = 40)
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Visualization

pelaChl_bxp <- ggplot(data = phyto_plankton_tbl, aes(x= time, y = PelaChl, fill = trt)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  ylim(0, 50) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette) + ## Adds color blind firendly palette
  ##  geom_jitter() +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: These are the outlying points. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_boxplot.html):

> The boxplot compactly displays the distribution of a continuous variable. It visualises five summary statistics (the median, two hinges and two whiskers), ***and all "outlying" points individually***.

The individual points you are seeing are "outliers" (though, as Roland has helpfully pointed out,"outlier" is a loaded term- often people think they can just remove any values from a dataset which are unusual or extreme, when they may be real data points which reflect the weirdness of the underlying data).

Comment: They are extreme values. "Outliers" is a too often misused term that should be avoided.

Comment: @Roland I agree- I added some information to clarify things. Let me know what you think :-)